Very high heating bill for my apartment
I need your suggestions regarding the heating bills of my apartment. It would be helpful if you share your experience in case you have faced similar situations or otherwise have suggestions.
I lived  in an apartment in Berlin from 2019 until February, 2024. I received a very high heating bill for the year 2021 and 2022,  more than 10 times the heating bill I received for the year 2020.
When I first received the bill for 2021, I notified the property management  about such an exceptionally high bill and asked to correct the bill. But they did not do anything and after one year sent even higher bill for the year 2022. I again asked them to correct the bill. This time they replied (probably because I gave notification to vacate) that they have checked the bill and it is correct and based on the readings of the meter installed in my apartment. But nobody ever came to my apartment to take the readings (not sure if the readings were automatically transferred to their record). Now they are asking me to pay the bill (More than 5000 Euros).
Any suggestions what I can do in this situation. I do not believe that the heating bill is correct. I had a small  apartment (approx. 31 square meter) with one room + small kitchen + bathroom. Nothing changed in the way I lived in the apartment in 2020. How can then heating costs increase more than tenfold for the same apartment and the same tenant?  Is it possible the meter installed are faulty? The meters were installed in my apartment in either 2020 or 2021 (do not remember exactly). Or could it be something else?
Would it be a good idea to consult a lawyer for this? I mean would I gain anything after paying fees for the lawyer and the legal process and going through all the trouble involved in the legal process. Is there a place/forum where I can get some help on this? Also I have returned to India. So I have to do everything from India only.
Thank you very much.

I think you’ll need to gather information before consulting a lawyer. How often did you personally read the meter and do you have a note of the readings during your tenancy? Did you check the reading when the new meter was first installed? Was there a charge for installing it? What records do you have of the bills and the resulting correspondence between yourself and the property management? How and when did you follow up with management after first challenging the bill in 2021? Were you on the same energy tariff for the whole tenancy? Was it fixed or variable? Did you make payments meanwhile?

An additional consideration is how much trouble it would be for you or for them to pursue this further. Did you recover your deposit or is that also in the balance? In a similar situation, I was able to negotiate the invoice down to the amount of the deposit, which didn't match either my or the landlord's claim but was a reasonable compromise as we both knew it would very difficult for either of us to force the other to disburse anything.


I lived  in an apartment in Berlin from 2019 until February, 2024. I received a very high heating bill for the year 2021 and 2022, more than 10 times the heating bill I received for the year 2020.

Some details would help give a more specific answer: Did you receive or or two invoices before this very high 2021 bill? If that's only one bill, it may have been a provision that was simply too low and once the first year had passed, you received an invoice reflecting the actual costs. This could happen through an honest mistake or because the landlord or an agent wanted to make the apartment look more attractive than it is.
As @quarague explained, the invoice should also detail how much energy you used and a price per unit of energy. How much did each of these increase? An actual ten-fold increase in the amount of energy you used would be surprising but an increase in price together with higher consumption would be more plausible.

When I first received the bill for 2021, I notified the property management about such an exceptionally high bill and asked to correct the bill. But they did not do anything and after one year sent even higher bill for the year 2022. I again asked them to correct the bill. This time they replied (probably because I gave notification to vacate) that they have checked the bill and it is correct and based on the readings of the meter installed in my apartment. But nobody ever came to my apartment to take the readings (not sure if the readings were automatically transferred to their record). Now they are asking me to pay the bill (more than 5000 Euros).

If there was no meter before 2020, what were the first invoice(s) based on? Is it €5000 for one year or for two years? Does that include any penalties as suggested by @Traveller? What about 2023? How much did they ask for that and if it is lower, is it because of a decrease in energy prices or lower use on your part?

Any suggestions what I can do in this situation. I do not believe that the heating bill is correct. I had a small apartment (approx. 31 square meter) with one room + small kitchen + bathroom. Nothing changed in the way I lived in the apartment in 2020. How can then heating costs increase more than tenfold for the same apartment and the same tenant? Is it possible the meter installed are faulty? The meters were installed in my apartment in either 2020 or 2021 (do not remember exactly). Or could it be something else?

What it could be is a significant increase due to the 2021 energy prices together a poor initial estimate. €2500 in utility costs for a year for a 31 square meter is high but not completely outside the realm of possibilities with poor thermal isolation and a cold winter. How high are you setting the heating (what temperature do you keep inside your apartment)?

Would it be a good idea to consult a lawyer for this? I mean would I gain anything after paying fees for the lawyer and the legal process and going through all the trouble involved in the legal process. Is there a place/forum where I can get some help on this? Also I have returned to India. So I have to do everything from India only.

If any of the hypotheses I raised are true then the bill may be accurate and as frustrating as it is to learn about it after one year, there isn't much you or a lawyer could do. If, on the other hand, it's actually €5000 for a year and you have evidence that you used a lot less energy in 2019, 2020, and 2023 then something could be amiss.

First, your heating bill should have not only a final monthly Euro amount but also some kind of units of heating used plus a price per unit. Depending on the type of heating this could be measured in kWh or in m^3 of hot water or litres of oil or something. This should allow you to find out whether you a) used 10 times more heating in the later years or b) a similar amount of heating became 10 times more expensive.
You should search online for typical German average amounts of heating used for apartments of your size (this can vary quite a bit depending on isolation) to get an idea whether the amount of heating on your bill looks reasonable or not.
You should search online for typical per unit costs for a rental apartment and again check whether what appears on your bill looks plausible for typical German heating contracts.
Finally, are the 5000 Euros the total amount over the 3 years 2021 until February 2024 combined? Then this sounds quite reasonable to me. Or is that an annual amount? Then this sounds too high for a 30 m^2 apartment but might be fine for a 100 m^2 due to high heating prices related to the war in Ukraine.

I may be wrong but reading between the lines, it sounds like the OP may not have paid anything after challenging the first bill in 2021. In which case, the €5,000 may well include a (possibly hefty) late payment fee(s)

@Traveller That is possible. It also seems possible that OP paid some lower amount for heating and 5000€ is the accumulated difference over 3 years. Only OP can know that.
